# Strategy to find the highest valued item in a list with imperfect measurements

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, statistical-inference

Suppose you have a set of items (rocks) that each contain a certain amount of precious metal.  The amount of precious metal contained in each rock is distributed over $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$
You have a device that imperfectly measures the amount of precious metal in each rock with an error that is distributed over $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$

Our goal is to find the rock that contains the most precious metal.

The cost of choosing the wrong rock is $C = v_n - v_a $ where $v_n$ is the value of the rock with the most precious metal, and $v_a$ is the value of the rock you chose.
Furthermore, each time you perform a measurement on a rock you have the added cost of $c_m$
We can thus find the total cost $C$ from the equation:  $C = (v_n - v_a) + (n*c_m)$
Where $n$ is the total number of measurements you performed.

What is the optimal strategy to minimize $C$?

Edit: I should add that $|S|$ the size of the set of rocks is known and that the true value of $v_n$ is unknown.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Don't we know to know how many rock there are in total?  This is a nice question.  Where does it come from?  How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, you are right that you need to know how many rocks you have.  I formulated the question myself to try to make a general problem that I've been thinking about for a while more concrete.  So far I have only run some simulations to try to find trends, but have not gotten very far with any rigorous formulations of a strategy.

Comment: Each measurement has a probability of finding a rock with a better $v$, and a certainty of costing $c_m$. You can figure out the expectation of how much the new $v_a$ will improve. You stop looking when that improvement < $c_m$. That sounds straightforward. But I don't see how to use the error distribution. I imagine you need to know the number of rocks. You don't need to know $v_n$.

Comment: On second thought, maybe you don't need to know the number of rocks.  We want to test the next rock if the expected increase in $v_a$ exceeds the cost of making the test.  If this expected net gain is negative, by linearity of expectation, it will be negative no matter how many more rocks we test.  This doesn't depend on how many rocks remain to be tested.

Comment: @saulspatz My original thought for creating a strategy was to test every rock, and then select a subset of the highest valued rocks and repeat this process until we are left with a single rock.  My main focus of interest was on dealing with imperfect measurements.  I would imagine that the number of rocks in the set and the cost of each measurement would effect what the optimal strategy is, and whether repeating measurements is ever worth it.

Comment: I was thinking that I would approach the problem by first assuming that the measurements were perfect.  However, if the focus is on measurement errors, this may not be fruitful.

Comment: if this were a real problem, you should be accounting for non-independence of the measurement errors.